# How to collect the final score by going through each column names?

Tags: matlab, indexing, cell-array

I have a cell array that has points and names

```
Points     NameList1        NameList2
[20]        'Mat'            'Ken'
[15]        'Ken'            'John'
[10]        'Mario'          'Mat'
[5]         'John'           'Harry'
[0]         'Kelly'          'Mario'
```

I would like to collect the points that everyone collected. I was planning on using the `unique` function to get the names and going to each column to see how many points everyone collected and storing it (example: 'Mat' [20,10]. The problem is I have no idea how to go through every column and collect the number.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another classic case of [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html).  `accumarray` works by using a bunch of keys and a bunch of values.  For those keys that are the same, the corresponding values get mapped to the same bin and the default behaviour of `accumarray` is to add up those values that get mapped to the same bin.  In your case, the keys would be the names and the values are the points.

What I would do is concatenate all of those names over all of the columns in your cell array into a single column vector, then create points vector that is duplicated for as many columns as we have names.  After, we can use [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to determine the list of all unique names (first output) and get a unique ID for each name that we see in the large list of names (third output).  From there, we can accumulate our points:

```
scores = {[20]        'Mat'            'Ken'
[15]        'Ken'            'John'
[10]        'Mario'          'Mat'
[5]         'John'           'Harry'
[0]         'Kelly'          'Mario'};

points = cell2mat(scores(:,1)); %// Get points and duplicate
points = repmat(points, size(scores,2)-1, 1);

%// Create list of all names
names = scores(:,2:end);

%// Find unique names and unique ID numbers
[unique_names, ~, id] = unique(names(:));

%// Calculate score
out = accumarray(id, points);
```

`out` will contain the scores for all players and `unique_names` will contain the names of all the people you're tallying the scores with.

Therefore, displaying both variables, we get:

```
>> unique_names

unique_names = 

    'Harry'
    'John'
    'Kelly'
    'Ken'
    'Mario'
    'Mat'

>> out

out =

     5
    20
     0
    35
    10
    30
```

As such, Harry got 5 points, John got 20 points, and so on.

Comment: very nicely explained. Thank you.